# Add node at end of linked list in c

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I am attempting to add a node to the end of a linked list. I use a void function and pass my struct into it, but once it has ran through the add function, my struct is still empty. here is the code.

```
struct part {
    char* name;
    float price;
    int quantity;
    struct part *next;
};

typedef struct part partType;

void addEnd(partType *item) {  
    partType *temp1=NULL, *temp2=NULL;
    char temp[100];  

    temp1 = (struct part *)malloc(sizeof(partType));  

    if (!temp1)
        printf("malloc failed\n");

    temp1->name = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);

    printf("Please enter item name: \n");
    fgets(temp, 100, stdin);     
    strcpy(temp1->name, temp);      

    printf("Please enter item price: \n");
    fgets(temp, 100, stdin);
    sscanf(temp, "%f", &temp1->price);      

    printf("Please enter item quantity: \n");
    fgets(temp, 100, stdin);
    sscanf(temp, "%d", &temp1->quantity);  

    // Copying the Head location into another node.  
    temp2 = item;  

    if (item == NULL) {  
        // If List is empty we create First Node.  
        item = temp1;  
        item->next = NULL;
        printf("%s%.2f\n%d\n", item->name, item->price, item->quantity);  
    } else {  
       // Traverse down to end of the list.  
       while (temp2->next != NULL)  
           temp2 = temp2->next;  

       // Append at the end of the list.  
       temp1->next = NULL;  
       temp2->next = temp1;
       printf("%s%.2f\n%d\n", item->name, item->price, item->quantity);
    }
}
```

item is null when it is initially passed into the function, but for some reason comes out null even though i have the if statement that sets item equal to temp1.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this with a debugger? That's often a great way to see how your variables are changing, and how your program flows through your control structures (if statements and loops). Use your IDE's built-in visual debugging tools, or use GDB via the commandline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify the value of the pointer, so you need an extra level of indirection:

```
void addEnd(partType **item)
{
   ...
   temp2 = *item;
   ...  
   if (*item == NULL)
   {
     *item = temp1;
     (*item)->next = NULL;
     printf("%s%.2f\n%d\n", (*item)->name, (*item)->price, (*item)->quantity);
     ...
}
```

and you would call this as

```
partType *newItem;
...
addEnd(&newItem);
```

Comment: ok i thought that may be the problem. i will try it and report back.

Comment: getting the error
"request for member 'next' in something that is not a structure" for the line 

    *item->next = NULL;

Comment: `*item->next` or `(*item)->next`?  Those parentheses aren't optional.

Comment: wait i just needed the brackets around *item it seems.

Comment: so i know for next time why aren't they?

Comment: Postfix operators like `->` have a higher precedence than unary operators like `*`, so `*item->next` is parsed as `*(item->next)`; unfortunately, in this particular case, `item` is not a pointer to a struct type (it's a pointer to a pointer to a struct), so it's not a valid operand for the `->` operator.  We need to dereference `item` *before* applying the `->` operator; hence the need for the parentheses.

Comment: i am trying to check to see if the list has been filled by printing it using a while loop that prints all the stuff in the node while it isnt null, moving a step down the list each time. can only seem to print the first node. Not sure if the add function is even working past that.

Comment: nevermind i had changed something by mistake earlier when appending the list. fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

If `item` is `NULL`, when you call the function, it is bound to be `NULL` *also after* the function. C doesn't know reference parameter, they are "simulated" by pointers. If you want to change a pointer within a function, you need a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a guess as you didn't actually show how you are calling this function. I'm assuming you have a pointer called item somewhere of type part set to NULL. You then call this function with that variable. This doesn't actually mean a pointer to a pointer of that type. It creates a local copy of that pointer variable when you perform that function call, which is currently pointing to NULL. You set the local copy of that item pointer to temp and then that local copy is lost at the end of the function.